# Prevent admin from making orders for out of stock products in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I don't want any out of stock products to be added in admin order page!

Refer to this topic [Prevent woocommerce to create manual order from out of stock products](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-woocommerce-to-create-manual-order-from-out-of-stock-products/)

Any tricks or custom code provide would appreciate much.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_validation', 'rmg_woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_validation', 10, 4 );
function rmg_woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_validation( $validation_error, $product, $order, $qty ) {
    if ( $validation_error && !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $validation_error->add( 'product-out-of-stock', __('Product Out of Stock', 'woocommerce') );
    }
    if ( $validation_error && ( $product->get_stock_quantity() < $qty ) ) {
        $validation_error->add( 'product-low-stock', __('Product low of Stock', 'woocommerce') );
    }
    return $validation_error;
}
```

You may need to add more logic to this as this is the simplest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help the code is working great as expected!!!

Comment: Hi @Reigel, I have another problem!  Although we can prevent admin from adding out of stock product, admin still able to edit product qty more than its stock !!!! What can I do to prevent such case?  There is an action hook for order item updating?

Comment: #Reigel thanks for your code but it is only works for adding new!  for editing not work!